# Como funcionam assinaturas assimétricas em JSON Webtokens (JWT)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, token, jwt

Recentemente comecei a estudar a possibilidade de começar a usar JSON Webtokens em meus projetos, dadas as suas vantagens. Pelo que entendi, existe uma forma simétrica e uma forma assimétrica de gerar a assinatura para os tokens. A simétrica parece ser a mais comum, que vi em vários exemplos, fazendo a assinatura a partir de uma mesma chave armazenada em algum lugar no sistema (me corrijam se estiver falando besteira), como por exempo nesta linha utilizando o pacote [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) com o Express do Node.js:

```
 var token = jwt.sign(user, app.get('superSecret'), {
     expiresInMinutes: 1440
 });
```

Nota-se que todas as assinaturas são baseadas no `superSecret`, previamente armazenado na variável `app`.

Se este é o método simétrico, como seria o assimétrico? Não entendo muito de criptografia, mas sei que quando falamos de chaves assimétricas, deve existir um par de chaves: uma privada e uma pública.

Como isso se enquadraria no processo de autenticação de uma aplicação web? Alguém poderia me explicar e/ou dar um exemplo do funcionamento do JWT com assinatura assimétrica?

E ainda, para esse propósito (autenticação em uma web app), qual dos dois métodos é mais seguro?

Answer (score 3):

O JWT ele é uma criptográfica assimétrica.

O JWT armazena uma chave privada, que vai ficar no seu servidor e quando o usuário solicitar a chave pública, o JWT usa a chave privada para gera a chave pública.

Para esclarecer os conceitos envolvidos.

- Criptografia simétrica

Uma chave secreta, que pode ser um número, uma palavra ou apenas uma seqüência de letras aleatórias, é aplicada ao texto de uma mensagem para alterar o conteúdo de uma determinada maneira. Por exemplo trocando uma vogal por uma letra p. Npstp caso substitui a lptra p por p, vocp p qupm conhpcp a vogal sabp lpr a psta mpnsagpm.

- Criptografia assimétrica

Qualquer mensagem (texto, arquivos binários ou documentos) que seja criptografada usando a chave pública só pode ser descriptografada, aplicando o mesmo algoritmo, e usando a chave particular correspondente.

No caso  o `supersecret` vai ser a chave secreta para gerar o token(chave pública) e também será usado quando o token for enviado para dizer se a chave é válida ou não.

Talvez você esteja confundindo a questão de ser síncrono e assíncrono do modulo jwt. Quando você usa o JWT dessa forma você trava o fluxo para aguardar o token, o código fica síncrono.

```
var token = jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, cert, { algorithm: 'RS256'});
```

E quando você envia um callback, ele se torna assíncrono.

```
jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, cert, { algorithm: 'RS256' }, function(token) {
  console.log(token);
});
```

**Segurança**

Com relação aos métodos mais seguros, o método assimétrico é o mais seguro, já que usam duas chaves e uma fica em segredo no servidor. (Cuidado para não vazar as chaves do servidor. Ou adicionar a chave e salvar no Github)

Quanto ao método assíncrono ou síncrono não faz diferença, quanto a segurança, mas faz diferença quanto a performance.

**Casos de uso**

- Criptografia simétrica.

No geral não é aconselhável em aplicações, já que a chave fica com mensagem. Mas você pode usar para gerar o seu `supersecret`. O padrão `[AES][1]` é simétrico e usado em alguns roteadores.

- Criptografia assimétrica.

Na internet onde você tem que deixar coisas públicas como o token para o seu usuário que está logado, é melhor forma. Afinal se alguém descobre a chave pública precisaria da chave privada para quebrar as informações. Boa parte das aplicações usam esse sistema.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta. Bem elucidativa. Poderia exemplificar casos em que seria melhor eu utilizar a criptografia assimétrica ao invés da simétrica?

Comment: Vou adicionar a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique no NPM o módulo chamado jwt-simple. Pode resolver seu problema facilmente. 
Transcrição do próprio NPM:

```
$ npm install jwt-simple

var jwt = require('jwt-simple');
var payload = { foo: 'bar' };
var secret = 'xxx';

// encode 
var token = jwt.encode(payload, secret);

// decode 
var decoded = jwt.decode(token, secret);
console.log(decoded); //=> { foo: 'bar' }
```

Comment: Opa! Então, quanto a esse método, eu não tenho nenhuma dúvida quanto ao funcionamento, inclusive é assim mesmo que estava fazendo no Node.js utilizando o pacote que mencionei na pergunta. A minha dúvida é na verdade o modo de funcionamento da assinatura Assimétrica. Creio que essa que comumente se faz, e que você demonstrou, é a simétrica, onde se usa o mesmo 'secret' para assinar todos os tokens...